# Why params is less common used than query strings in HTTP URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, url

I'm reading the book, HTTP - The Definitive Guide, from which I get the URL general format:

```
<scheme>://<user>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<path>;<params>?<query>#<frag>
```

The `<params>` part said,

> The path component for HTTP URLs can be broken into path segments. Each segment can have its own params. For example:
>
> http://www.joes-hardware.com/hammers;sale=false/index.html;graphics=true

In my opinion, path params can also be used to query resources like query strings, but why it's barely seen?

And I'm a Rails developer, and I haven't seen its usage or specification in Rails. Does Rails not support it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ask several questions

**Why do we not see `;params=value` much?**
Because query parameters using `?=&` are widely supported, like in `PHP`, `.net`, `ruby` etc.. with convenient functions like `$_GET[]`.

While params delimited by `;` or `,` do not have these convenient helper functions. You do encounter them at `Rest` api's, where they are used in the `htaccess` or the controller to get relevant parameters.

**Does Ruby support params delimited with `;`?**

Once you obtain the current url, you can get all parameters with a simple regex call. This is also why they are used in `htaccess` files, because they are easily regexed (is that a word?).

---

Both parameter passing structures are valid and can be used, the only clear reason why one is used more often than the other is because of preference and support in the different languages.